# $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^5-y^2)$ is a principal ideal domain?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^5-y^2)$ is a PID? What is the general method to solve this kind of problem!?

Comment: What is $R$? Is $R = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Here R means real numbers.

Answer (score 4):

I assume $R$ is a ring with unit.

Well, *one* way is to recall that every PID is a UFD and search for a violation of unique factorization.  In the quotient, we have the equivalence $y^2 = x^5$, so maybe we can find a factorization of something close to this.

I note that $y^2 -1 = x^5 - 1$ and we have two distinct (by comparing $x$-degree and $y$-degree) factorizations: 
$$  x^5 - 1 = (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)  $$
and 
$$  y^2 - 1 = (y-1)(y+1)  \text{.}  $$